# Why do I have 2 classes for this .net core webapi endpoint?

Tags: c#, oop, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to wrap my head around .net API project structure, using the default webapi template

```
dotnet new webapi -n quickstart
```

Why do I have 2 classes for this weatherforcast endpoint?

[image]

The public class `WeatherForecast.cs` is just a public class but it looks like it's being used like an interface. It's accessed in the controller like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    var rng = new Random();
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}
```

But to create a new endpoint I just needed to add a new controller `DefaultController.cs` and there I just did this and it worked:

```
[HttpGet]
public object Get()
{
    var responseObject = new
    {
        Status = "Up"
    };
    _logger.LogInformation($"Status pinged: {responseObject.Status}");
    return responseObject;
}
```

Why would I create a separate class like is done with WeatherForecast? What is this pattern called and how is it getting hooked up to the controller? I guess I'm also confused because WeatherForecast.cs is just a regular class not an interface but it's being converted to an interface maybe? When digging through the docs, I'm having trouble figuring out what this pattern/structure is and beginner level docs that describe the "why" part of it

### Edit

Is WeatherForecast.cs a *model* class? Because when I research it, I see a more common pattern seems to be putting model classes in a "models" folder not in the root of the project.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  WeatherForcast seems to be your model.  I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: `but its being converted to an interface maybe` What makes you say that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking about "WeatherForecast.cs" ... yet you've failed to *show* us your WeatherForecast.cs

But yes, it probably *IS* a class that's being used in a manner similar to the way Java programmers might use Java "interfaces".

Specifically, it probably has [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) and might look something like this:

**WeatherClass.cs**

```
public class WeatherClass 
{
  public double TemperatureC { get; set; }
}
```

This is a "model".  Read through this link for more details:

> https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/mvc-model
>
> The model classes represents domain-specific data and business logic
> in the MVC application. It represents the shape of the data as public
> properties and business logic as methods.